# weighted random for one value only

Tags: python, random, weighted

The following line returns a pair of coordinates

```
coordinates = random.random()*640.0, random.random()*480.0
```

How to get a particular pair of coordinates for example (100.0, 100.0) with probability 0.03. Coordinates are generated in a loop, a number of loops is different every run, but the maximum of loops is 1000.

I'm not sure what it is. Google says it's weighted random. But all examples contain the list of probabilities, I have only one particular value with a given probability.

EDIT: Sorry guys, it's uniform sampling and it's floats.

Comment: It's clear what you want to happen in 3% of the cases. It is not clear what you want to happen in the remaining 97% of the cases. Could you clarify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve the problem in two steps:

Step 1) Make (100,100) come up 3% of the time - Roll a random value from 0 to 1.  If the value is less than 0.03 then return (100, 100), otherwise continue to Step 2.

Step 2) Handle the other 97% case.  Return a random coordinate between whatever values you want the way you're already doing it.  It's not really clear what you want to happen here - Based on your example, I'm guessing you want to pick a uniformly distributed value between (0,0) and (640,480).

There's an extremely small chance that you'll get (100, 100) in step 2.  If it's super important that the probability of getting (100, 100) is exactly 3% and not slightly more than 3%, then check for (100,100) in step 2 and re-roll if you get it by chance.  It's so incredibly unlikely if you're generating float coordinates that you can just omit this check.

If your coordinates are integers only, then accidentally getting (100, 100) is still pretty unlikely, but it could still happen.  See pjs's answer

Comment: it's uniform distribution (continuous) for the rest of randoms. And I generate floats.

Comment: Then this is the right way to solve this problem, and you should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

In what follows, I'm assuming that you want the 97% probability to uniformly distributed across the `640*480 - 1` integer coordinates that aren't (100, 100).

My proposal is similar to Pete's, but with exact probabilities (established by `Fraction`) set so that in the second stage the designated coordinate (100, 100) is not a special case.  First, let's figure out the exact probabilities needed:

```
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> p = Fraction(97, 100) / (640 * 480 - 1)
>>> p
Fraction(1, 316700)
>>> remainder = 1 - (640 * 480 * p)
>>> remainder
Fraction(95, 3167)
```

We have `97/100`'s of the probability distributed across the non-designated coordinates, so each should occur with probability `1 / 316700`.  Let's also put that much probability in the designated coordinate.  In that case, the *remaining* probability at (100, 100) is calculated as `remainder`.  The algorithm then becomes:

```
if random.random() <= remainder:
   coordinates = 100, 100
else:
   coordinates = random.randint(0, 639), random.randint(0, 479)
```

If you really did mean to have the outcomes be continuous except for the probability spike at (100, 100), then Pete's answer is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to generate a list with 0.03*N entries of (100,100), and 0.97*N random entries, then randomly reorder that list... For large N, though, @PeteBaughman's answer is probably better...

Comment: This may actually be better, or worse, depending on the exact requirements.  For N = 1000, this method would guarantee that you got (100,100) exactly 30 times.  If you were randomly picking coordinates and expect (100,100) to have a probability of .03, then you might get (100,100) 29 or 31 or 28 etc times for every 1000 picks